# HTML filter table

Tags: python, html

Hi i have a table that is generated through python using the tabulate function, i want to add filtering to this table, however i keep getting stuck and nothing comes of it i have this so far i want it to be able to search what failed and what passed how do i make a function that properly filters it?

```
           //Filter table
            $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $("#myTable td").filter(function () {
                    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                });
            });
            
 });
</script>
<button class="displayvar" onclick="displayvar();">Display detailed reason</button>
<button class="displayvar2" onclick="displayvar2();">Display Testcase log divided by testcase</button>



</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="flip">Show table</div>
   <div id="panel">
   <br />
   <span>Search by testcase</span>
   <input id="myInput" class="fortextbox"  type="text" placeholder="Search.." />
   <br /><br /><br />  <tbody id="myTable">
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th style="text-align: right;">  S.No</th><th>Testcase                    </th><th>Result:  </th><th>SECTION                      </th><th>Reason                        </th><th>Analysis    </th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">     0</td><td>CallsiteMemLeakReportInitial</td><td>FAILED   </td><td>section test_case            </td><td>Mem leak found before the run\</td><td>Script issue</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">     1</td><td>FinalMemLeakReport          </td><td>FAILED   </td><td>section check_final_mem_leaks</td><td>Memory Leaks Found\           </td><td>Script issue</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">     2</td><td>CallsiteMemLeakReportFinal  </td><td>FAILED   </td><td>section test_case            </td><td>Mem leak found before the run\</td><td>Script issue</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">     3</td><td>InitialMemLeakReport        </td><td>PASSED   </td><td>                             </td><td>                              </td><td>            </td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">     4</td><td>TriggerInterfaceFlaps       </td><td>PASSED   </td><td>                             </td><td>                              </td><td>            </td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">     5</td><td>TriggerVlanInterfaceFlaps   </td><td>PASSED   </td><td>                             </td><td>                              </td><td>            </td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">     6</td><td>TriggerClearIPOspfProcess   </td><td>PASSED   </td><td>                             </td><td>                              </td><td>            </td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">     7</td><td>TriggerClearIPDTProcess     </td><td>PASSED   </td><td>                             </td><td>                              </td><td>            </td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">     8</td><td>TriggerClearIPRouteProcess  </td><td>PASSED   </td><td>                             </td><td>                              </td><td>            </td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">     9</td><td>TriggerClearAuthSessions    </td><td>PASSED   </td><td>                             </td><td>                              </td><td>            </td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">    10</td><td>TriggerClearFlowMonitorCace </td><td>PASSED   </td><td>                             </td><td>                              </td><td>            </td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">    11</td><td>TriggerBgpNeighborFlap      </td><td>PASSED   </td><td>                             </td><td>                              </td><td>            </td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">    12</td><td>TriggerVlanInterfaceFlaps   </td><td>PASSED   </td><td>                             </td><td>                              </td><td>            </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The function i have currenty doesnt work,, not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: If that is how you actually have your HTML, it is thoroughly invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `tbody` in excess, with the attribute `id="#myTable"` which should belong to `table` instead.

Here there is your script with two little changes:

```
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").slice(1).filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
});
```

Comment: still doesnt work....i type in the search box nothing comes jp

Comment: @KhizarSayed this script will hide rows from the table which don't contain the searched word, while showing those that contain it. Is this your desired outcome? If not, sorry but i haven't understood it.

Comment: No that’s exactly what I want however when I run the code it does nothing